# How to subframe particle emitter parented to a Bone?

Tags: animation, particles, armature

I parented a particle emitter to a character's armature (a bone in the armature). The idea is to create a continuous trail of particles that the characters leaves behind as he flies by.
If I parent the emitter to a bone in the armature, the trail becomes 'patchy' and 'stepped', like the emmitter is not considering subframes, only whole frames.

I tested animating the emitter directly, in the same speed as the character, and the trail is continuous (as I need it to be) and not stepped like it is when parented to a bone. But I need to parent it, because I want it to be precise and follow exactly the same path as the character.

Why does parenting to the armature make the emission not continuous? Is there a way to fix this?
Edit: added a screenshot below: The trail becomes a 'dotted' line as the character gains speed, instead of being a continuous trail.
[image: The trail becomes a 'dotted' line as the character gains speed, instead of being a continuous trail.]

Comment: There's probably a better way but the fastest solution is to just double your particle count.

Comment: Interesting ... If none I will check that later ... Try Constraint Location instead of parenting? BTW @NascentSpace doubled amount will just generates doubled count in steps.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad, hmm. Only other idea I have is to add a second object that somehow trails behind the first particle emitter itself but at such a distance that it fills in extra particles behind it. Not sure how else this could be done.

Comment: Turning up particle count doesn't solve it, it creates more particles but they are all being emited at the same intervals, so they are clumped together creating a dashed line instead of a continuous stream. I'll try using the constraint location instead of parenting.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue still happens even with location constraint instead of parenting. I also tried the 'child of' constraint and also did not work.
I wonder if armatures don't consider subframes or if it's something else. I don't know what it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only one way I found is to use *Output Properties > Dimensions >* **Time Remapping**

[image]

[image]

Top row are particles emitted from animated Plane.
Bottom row are particles emitted from Plane parented to Bone.

[image]

Notes:

- Subframes doesn't help because issue is related to a Bone that jumps to next frame (same as anim Plane, but there (for some reason) it works as expected.
- For that I tried to add **Step** Modifier, that let you add steps even in between two frames (or negative), but even steps were visible on Timeline, zero influence for particles as well.

[image]

- Constraint didn't work (parented Plane to Armature as well)
- I didnt post this answer almost week ago, just because when I tried it I probably didn't refresh cache to see influence ... the only one way to refresh cache that works for me is to change **Number** of particles every time I do same change in setup.

### Edit

According to this closed [bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T41127) from 2014 it is marked by Sergey as known limitation planned to be fixed with new particle system. Lukas created already [fix](https://developer.blender.org/rBc24a23f264d2c7001c61ca6e11c66b8c372e1d2a) at the same year, but wasn't published and was moved on [TO DO list](https://developer.blender.org/T55362)

But check blend file attached on bug report link. You have two other options

- *Bake Action*
- *Constraint > Follow Path*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The time remap workaround indeed seems to be the best option at the moment. In my case I just ended up animating the emitter independently (it was a short animation so it wasn't that difficult), but it might be useful for future projects. Hope they fix this soon, though (it seems like a design flaw to me).

Comment: Little edit with a few options.